# Cast within If Statement

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to cast an object from within an if statement?

The below code is not valid apparently:

```
' DriversLicense_Expiry is of type Object
If (DriversLicense_Expiry = Nothing OrElse (DriversLicense_Expiry as DateTime) > DateTime.Now) Then ...
```

I've also tried to cast like this but when its not defined it causes an exception:

```
Dim dtDriversLicenceExpiry As DateTime = DriversLicense_Expiry;
```

Sometimes `DriversLicense_Expiry` wont be defined thus be null

Comment: If you used `DateTime?` in the first place you wouldn't need an `Object`.

Comment: Your code not even a `vb.net` - it is only looking like vb.net

Comment: What is original type of `DriversLicense_Expiry`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to cast in Visual Basic you'd have to use the `DirectCast`, or possibly even the `CType`, function.

`(DriversLicense_Expiry as DateTime)` is indeed an invalid statement, since the `As` keyword is only used when declaring variables.

The structure of the `DirectCast` or `CType` function is:

```
DirectCast(<object to cast>, <type to cast to>)
```

With that said, here's a correct approach:

```
If DriversLicense_Expiry = Nothing OrElse DirectCast(DriversLicense_Expiry, DateTime) > DateTime.Now Then
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
If (DriversLicense_Expiry = Nothing OrElse
       Convert.ToDateTime(DriversLicense_Expiry) > DateTime.Now)
```